# Exibir Visual Python no Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi

Ao usar a biblioteca matplotlib no Power BI aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:
"O processo do Python terminou inesperadamente, portanto, o visual não pode ser exibido. Tente executálo novamente."
Como solucionar esse problema?

```
# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Japan, Year)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()
```

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(dataset.Year,dataset.Japan)

plt.show()

[image: Erro Power BI]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Solução que encontrei:
Criar um novo environment dentro do Anaconda Navigator e o usar como diretório do PowerBI

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]